# Phpmyadmin not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have trouble during running Phpmyadmin.

Error is

> ## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I am using,

wampserver 2.2

PHP version 5.3.13

MySql Version 5.5.24

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Wampserver have a very active forum which has helped solve similar issues arising from a multitude of causes.  Check out http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2

Listing the following is helpful to get started:
1. OS Version
2 WampServer version
3. Apache version
4. MySQL version
5. PHP version